# ANOVA table for mixed (nested design) model in R

Tags: r, self-study, mixed-model

I am trying to get an ANOVA table for a mixed model in R with nested design fit with package `lme4`, function `lmer()` in R. When I obtain the ANOVA table, R includes only the sums of squares for the fixed factor, and does not include anything for the random factor. Beyond R usage I'm questioning the underlying statistical process at work here - shouldn't random factors be included on an ANOVA table for a mixed model?

For example, I fit the model as:

```
lmer(response ~ A + (1 | A:B))  # where A is fixed, B is random, and B is nested within A.
```

I use the code below and just obtain output for the A fixed factor:

```
anova(lmer(response ~ A + (1 | A:D)))

   Sum Sq  Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F.value    Pr(>F)    
A 0.19812 0.099058     2     9  33.437 6.818e-05 ***
```